# Search through file for IP addresses x.x.x.0 and x.x.x.255

Tags: regex, vim, notepad++, ip-address

So searching through a list of about 10,000 ip addresses and I need to remove all of the x.x.x.0 and x.x.x.255's from the list. I've searched for quite a while now with no success. I'm using vim or notepad++ for this, but could use some programming given the right direction..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "searched"? Have you tried any regular expressions? `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.(0|255)` should trivially do it.

Comment: That actually worked perfectly! Thanks!!! I'm not too familiar with regular expressions, but it's definitely something I'll be looking into. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is extremely localized and too broad at the same time!

Answer (score 1):

Would comment but cannot,

you should also be able to use grep for a simple 1 liner:

```
grep -Pv '([0-9]{1,3}.){3}(0|255)' [inputfile] > [outputfile]
```

Comment: This will match `abc 123456789.1.1.0002589647000xyz ...` or `0000000`